# Set the position of radio button and entry in same column but the result was not allign

Tags: python, tkinter, grid, geometry, tkinter-entry

I was setting the position of my entry to be at the same row as the text"Specific Location" by using Grid Geometry Manager,but the final result turns out to be like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bugf0.jpg).I just want to know why the position will not according to the setting and the ways to solve it thanks^^

Here is the Coding for how i set the entry and radio button

```
 tm_label = Label(self.radioframe, text = "Tracing Method")
    tm_label.grid(row=0, columnspan=2 ,sticky = W)

    self.radioframe.LT = Radiobutton(
        self.radioframe, text="Live Tracing",
        variable=self.traceMethodSelect, value="LT",
        anchor=W).grid(row=1, column = 0, sticky = W)

    self.radioframe.SL= Radiobutton(
        self.radioframe, text="Specific Location",
        variable=self.traceMethodSelect, value="SL",
        anchor=W).grid(row=2, column = 0, sticky = W)

    location_ent =Entry(root)
    location_ent.grid(row =2, column = 1, sticky = W)
```

my whole code is here:

```
from tkinter import *

class TracingInterface(Frame):
def __init__(self, root):
    root.minsize(width=700, height=500)
    root.maxsize(width=700, height=500)
    Frame.__init__(self, root)
    Grid.config(self)
    self.TracingMethod()
def TracingMethod(self):


    self.traceMethodSelect = StringVar()
    self.traceMethodSelect.set("LT")

    self.radioframe = Frame(self)
    self.radioframe.grid()

    tm_label = Label(self.radioframe, text = "Tracing Method")
    tm_label.grid(row=0, columnspan=2 ,sticky = W)

    self.radioframe.LT = Radiobutton(
        self.radioframe, text="Live Tracing",
        variable=self.traceMethodSelect, value="LT",
        anchor=W).grid(row=1, column = 0, sticky = W)

    self.radioframe.SL= Radiobutton(
        self.radioframe, text="Specific Location",
        variable=self.traceMethodSelect, value="SL",
        anchor=W).grid(row=2, column = 0, sticky = W)

    location_ent =Entry(root)
    location_ent.grid(row =2, column = 1, sticky = W)
root = Tk()
root.title("Windows User Activity History Tracing and Analysing System")
tif= TracingInterface(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to draw location_ent inside the same container widget `self.radioframe` that holds the radiobuttons. This means you need to change:

`location_ent =Entry(root)`

**to:**

`location_ent =Entry(self.radioframe)`.

**Demo**

If you perform the modification above, you will get what you expect:

[image]

Comment: Thanks For you help.